# Disable telephone number links in facebook like iframe

Tags: ios, web, facebook-like, mobile-safari

I recently added a facebook like button to one of our pages. Everything works fine except ios sees the number of facebook likes, thinks it's a phone number, and turns it into a link.

I've read around and

```
<meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no">
```

should disable automatic phone links.  The problem is, the like button is added as an iframe so I have no way to insert the above meta tag into the document.  Adding it to the containing document does nothing.

Has anyone found a way around this issue?